# how can i create an osgi bundle cum executable jar using maven

Tags: java, maven, maven-assembly-plugin, osgi-bundle

i want to create an osgi bundle which can run like an executable jar. Is there any plugin in maven which can help me do this task.

like in case of working in osgi, its blueprint should run and in case of jar application, its manifest should run.

Comment: You need to pick an OSGi container, like [felix usage](http://www.gridshore.nl/2008/02/13/using-maven-to-create-an-osgi-bundle-osgi-felix-sample-step-2/), and with the OSGi plugin everything should go smooth.

Comment: i am working with karaf

Comment: Then [karaf](http://karaf.apache.org/manual/latest-2.2.x/developers-guide/archetypes.html) offers much to read; I think there is a **karaf-blueprint-archetype** as maven project template - no experience.